# Inheritance from TextBoxBase

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a library (.dll) file, and I want to create a little custom TextBox called FatherTextBox, so I started by deriving from TextBoxBase (an abstract class).

After coding the custom logic, I noticed that I get this error message:

```
The type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase' has no constructors defined
```

So I guess this is not a option:

```
    public FatherTextBox() : base()
    {

    }
```

My questions are:

1. What is the way to inherit from an abstract class without a constructor?
2. Why doesn't TextBoxBase have a constructor?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.aspx):

> You do not typically inherit from TextBoxBase. To create your own text
>   control class, inherit from TextBox or RichTextBox.

`TextBoxBase` has an `internal` constructor, which is why you can't call it.

Comment: so is not possible to inhrit from TextBoxBase?

Comment: @samy correct. Inherit from `TextBox` or `RichTextBox`, or something else similar to what you want.

Comment: Ok, i will do that Thanks :) but i wonder, why did they creat TextBoxBase if we cant use it?

Comment: nvm i understand it now, is for microsft personal use.

Comment: look my post, why you not can use it.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the source code of the `TextBoxBase` class, there are two constructors:

```
internal TextBoxBase()
{
    base.SetState2(2048, true);
    this.textBoxFlags[TextBoxBase.autoSize | TextBoxBase.hideSelection | TextBoxBase.wordWrap | TextBoxBase.shortcutsEnabled] = true;
    base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.FixedHeight, this.textBoxFlags[TextBoxBase.autoSize]);
    base.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.StandardClick | ControlStyles.StandardDoubleClick | ControlStyles.UseTextForAccessibility, false);
    this.requestedHeight = base.Height;
}
```

and

```
static TextBoxBase()
{
    // Note: this type is marked as 'beforefieldinit'.
    TextBoxBase.autoSize = BitVector32.CreateMask();
    TextBoxBase.hideSelection = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.autoSize);
    TextBoxBase.multiline = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.hideSelection);
    TextBoxBase.modified = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.multiline);
    TextBoxBase.readOnly = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.modified);
    TextBoxBase.acceptsTab = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.readOnly);
    TextBoxBase.wordWrap = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.acceptsTab);
    TextBoxBase.creatingHandle = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.wordWrap);
    TextBoxBase.codeUpdateText = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.creatingHandle);
    TextBoxBase.shortcutsEnabled = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.codeUpdateText);
    TextBoxBase.scrollToCaretOnHandleCreated = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.shortcutsEnabled);
    TextBoxBase.setSelectionOnHandleCreated = BitVector32.CreateMask(TextBoxBase.scrollToCaretOnHandleCreated);
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_ACCEPTSTABCHANGED = new object();
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_BORDERSTYLECHANGED = new object();
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_HIDESELECTIONCHANGED = new object();
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_MODIFIEDCHANGED = new object();
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_MULTILINECHANGED = new object();
    TextBoxBase.EVENT_READONLYCHANGED = new object();
}
```

The first constructor is internal, so only the same assembly that defines the type has access to it. The second one is a static constructor, it's called on the first access of the class.

Now the answers to your questions:

1. If an abstract class has not a constructor it is not intended to be used for inheritance.
   There are other classes e.g. `TextBox` or `RichTextBox` for your needs.
2. The architect of the class `TextBoxBase` designed a textbox base for all textboxes with a common OOP principe: Encapsulation. Encapsulation is for short the  hiding of implementation details of a complex type. And the `TextBoxBase` is quite complex.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
   class Txt:TextBox

    {
        public Txt():base()
        {

        }
    }
```